# C# webclient cannot download text from web

Tags: c#, webclient

I am working on a project to get text from [this website](http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsio180629.htm).
But when I tested it in Visual Studio, I've got some error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: solutionDirectory

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        String temp = client.DownloadString("http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsio180629.htm");
        Console.Write(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem with the code you presented, which other than a missing `using` works fine.

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Please use HttpClient Which is very good Option Compare to webClient
And your problem is sounds like your project (vcxproj) file isn't setup properly.

So create New Application Simply and run this Code.

[Here you find Actually Difference](http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/)

```
 Stream client = Task.Run(()=>new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsio180629.htm").Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()).Result;
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream("D://data.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
 {
     client.CopyTo(fileStream);
 }
```

Full Working Code:-

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stream client = Task.Run(()=>new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsio180629.htm").Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()).Result;
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream("D://data.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                client.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With Await

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            data();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static async void data()
        {
            var client = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsio180629.htm");
            var data= await client.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream("D://data.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                data.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC Task.Run is not required, since the GetAsync method is already running async when possible. And please use await, and not result. Result is blocking, await isn't.

Comment: whatever the methods and code are in task.run is not a blocking @Mafii

Comment: But the call to `.Result` is, that's what I said.

Comment: Invoking `Result` on any task that isn't complete is an anti-pattern that will eventually mess you up. Don't wait by blocking on tasks. Also, in your async example, the top-level `Main` method can now be declared as async : `static async Task Main(string[] args){}`, thereby negating the need for fire-and-forget.